# jquery change input value when scroll to div

Tags: jquery

## Edited:

resolved by [#24979865](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979663/jquery-change-input-value-when-scroll-to-div#24979865)

I tried to change value of input when the mouse scrolled to that page.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ya7dz/3/)

HTML :

```
<div class="pagenum">
    Page num: <input type="text" id="pagenum"> / 3
</div>
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="page" id="page-1" data-page-no="1">
        This is div #1
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="page-2" data-page-no="2">
        This is div #2
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="page-3" data-page-no="3">
        This is div #3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-container{
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 1500px;
}
.page {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px;
}
.pagenum {
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
}
```

JS :

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var pagenum = $('.page').attr('data-page-no');
  $("#pagenum").val(pagenum);
});
```

But it can not do as I want.

Anybody can help me?

More: when filling a number to input box, I want to animate to that page.

Thanks for edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the jQuery code that I use:

```
var disable_scroll = false;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    if(disable_scroll == false){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#page-1").offset().top){
           var pagenum = $("#page-1").attr('data-page-no');
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#page-2").offset().top){
           var pagenum = $("#page-2").attr('data-page-no');
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#page-3").offset().top){
           var pagenum = $("#page-3").attr('data-page-no');
        }
        $("#pagenum").val(pagenum);
    }
});
$("#pagenum").on('input',function(){
    $(".page").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('data-page-no') == $("#pagenum").val()){
            disable_scroll = true;
            var selected = $(this);
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 1
            }, function(){
                var pagenum = $(selected).attr('data-page-no');
                $("#pagenum").val(pagenum);
                disable_scroll = false;
            });
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ya7dz/5/)...

Answer (score 0):

try this....

`$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(50, 100);
    var pagenum = $(elem).attr("data-page-no");
    $(".pagenum > input").val(pagenum);
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp=document.getElementById("page-2").getBoundingClientRect();   
    if(temp.top>-50 && temp.top<50)
        $("#pagenum").val(2);
    else
        $("#pagenum").val(1);
```

Use the getBoundingClientRect() function to get the position of your div with respect to viewport and show page number depending on the value

I have done it for a particular div now you can use a foreach lop and check the values of all your divs on the page and show the page number accordingly